# How to insert React element into string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I would like to add React component into the string as JSX like this

```
const name = <a href="#"> World </a>
const a = 'Hello, {name}'
return <div>{a}</div>
```

how can I get the following output

```
<div> Hello, <a href="#">World</a></div>
```

Comment: @Rustam D9RS's answer below is great, but unless you're doing anything particularly complex with your assignment to JSX, something like this is usually simpler: `const name = 'World'; const href='#'; return <div><a href={href}>{name}</a></div>`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a string; instead, you also need to use JSX syntax (this won't work with a string):

```js
const name = <a href="/">World</a>;
const a = <>Hello, {name}</>;
return <div>{a}</div>;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just use another function component to get the other HTML part, and then add it to the main app return function inside `{}`, here is a working snippet:

```js
function name() { 
  return (<a href="#"> World </a>);
}

const App = () => {
  const a = `Hello, `
  return (
    <div>{a} {name()}</div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```